# printing sql query just before execution in php

Tags: php, sql, sql-server

my database is in SSMS and i am using custom php for retrieving  data i have made connection and also execute query which is giving me result but now i want to print/ echo query right before  execution

i have tried last_query() function but not working for me 
i have searched but results are for different database 
my query is prepared by variables in loop

this is my connection

```
$ServerName='DESKTOP-HCLLKV5';
$ConnectionInfo=array("Database"=>"SalesCampaign2019_1H" ,"CharacterSet"=>"UTF-8");
$Conn_sis=sqlsrv_connect($ServerName,$ConnectionInfo);

if($Conn_sis)
{   
    if(($DistinctCompany=sqlsrv_query($Conn_sis,
        "SELECT dbo.WalkerItContacts.ConcatKey , 
         dbo.WalkerItContacts.CompanyName,
         dbo.WalkerItContacts.EmployeeCity,
         dbo.WalkerItContacts.EmployeeAddress1
         FROM dbo.WalkerItContacts
         GROUP BY dbo.WalkerItContacts.ConcatKey,
         dbo.WalkerItContacts.CompanyName,
         dbo.WalkerItContacts.EmployeeCity,
         dbo.WalkerItContacts.EmployeeAddress1
         HAVING count(distinct dbo.WalkerItContacts.CompanyName) = 1
         order by dbo.WalkerItContacts.CompanyName")) !== false)    
         {
            print_r(last_query()); 
// here i want to check my query 

            exit("first");
            while($DistinctCompany_result = sqlsrv_fetch_object( $DistinctCompany ))
            {
```

this is my first query there are further more queries on the same file

Comment: FYI: `SSMS` is a client/tool to connect to Database engine. Its not a relational Database.

Comment: can you please elaborate i have reason to use SSMS  application is already in ssms and i cant change database so i connect my php to ssms